# Trying to update to php7 from centos 6

Tags: php, centos

I am having trouble to update my php version to php7 everything I Try to do I get the error.
Error: File contains no section headers. file: file:///etc/yum.repos.d/upgrade.repo, line: 1

Comment: Seems like you have a syntax error in /etc/yum.repos.d/upgrade.repo. You need to fix it or post it contents here so people can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the file : file:///etc/yum.repos.d/upgrade.repo and everything worked fine.